# syntastic - Disable automatic compilation of Java

Tags: vim

How can I tell Syntastic to not compile my Java code on save? I have tried following in my `.vimrc`:

`let g:syntastic_disabled_filetypes = ['java']`

`let g:syntastic_java_checker='checkstyle'`

`let g:syntastic_java_checker=''`

Comment: vim shouldn't be compiling your code automatically by default. What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Good point. It seems I am unable to prevent Syntastic from compiling my java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
                           \ 'active_filetypes': ['foo', 'bar'],
                           \ 'passive_filetypes': ['java'] }
```

This should work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the current version of syntastic. 'java' should be 'javac' (I suspect), but no matter where I put this directive it doesn't seem to be picked up.

Comment: Worked for me in spf13 after adding it to ~/.vimrc.local. Side effect is that it also disabled syntax checking for C =(

Answer (score 10):

This is something of a hack, but you can trick Syntastic into not loading the `javac` checker by pretending it's already loaded, by placing this in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:loaded_syntastic_java_javac_checker = 1
```

This option is superior to `g:syntastic_mode_map` since it doesn't require you to explicitly list all of the file types you want to be actively checked.