# Vim Syntastic produces "package org.junit does not exist" error when saving java file

Tags: java, vim, junit, syntastic

so I have a problem using vim with Syntastic for java. I spent hours looking for a solution but none of the dozens of questions seem to solve my problem.

I have some java files and a `lib/` folder containing (among other files) a junit.jar file. I'm using `ant` to compile the java files and I'm using `ant test` for testing. Everything works.

But every time I save my test class file in vim, it gives me these errors in Location List (some kind of error list):

> ClassTest|5 col 17 error| package org.junit does not exist
>
> ClassTest |6 col 17 error| package org.junit does not exist
>
> ClassTest |17 col 4 error| cannot find symbol (The @Test thing)

As I said, it's still working, the only problem is that vim/Syntastic can't find the `junit.jar` file, I guess. I just want these errors to go away :D

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937042/syntastic-disable-automatic-compilation-of-java

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm using syntactic. Also, I don't want to disable the compilation. It's incredibly useful for everything else. So I want to fix it, that it's also working with junit

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't even know this was something vim can do. From Googling it though it sounds like you must be using `Syntastic`. Does `:SyntasticJavacEditClasspath` do anything for you? If so, apparently that is where you can edit the classpath so the plugin can find things like `junit`.

Comment: That seems to be it. I think I actually use Syntastic. Thing is, I can't find out how to add the unit file. The command you gave me opens an empty file

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with this plugin, or with ant, so I can't help much, but at least now you know what to Google for. At a high level, from what I can tell [here](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues/434) you want to configure the plugin's classpath to be aware of the directory where `ant` is outputting the compiled `.java` files. Good luck.